# Como importar um componente React externo para o Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web, front-end, react

Olá, eu queria importar um componente externo React, gerado em webpack (Bundle.js) para o minha aplicação Asp.net MVC.
Estou tentando importar o arquivo "Bundle.js" para minha página e processar o componente React na tag script babel, mas nada acontece.
Qual é a maneira correta de importar um componente externo de uma biblioteca webpack em uma View?

Segue um exemplo de como estou fazendo, "CustomTextBox" é o componente que quero utilizar que esta dentro do bundle.js:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">

    ReactDOM.render(
    <CustomTextbox />,
        document.getElementById('timer')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Coloca esse script `ReactDOM.render(` dentro do componente para o webpack empacotar tudo. Senão tens de exportar o ReactDOM para o espaço global e os componentes que estejam nesse `bundle.js``